# Explanation needed: $g \,\colon [0,2] \to \Bbb R \,$ be a twice continuously differentiable function

Tags: numerical-methods

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $\,\,g \, \colon [0,2] \to \Bbb R \,$ be a twice continuously differentiable function. If $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}g(x)dx \approx 2 g(1),$ then the error in the approximation is :
>
> 1. $\frac{g'(\xi)}{12}$ for some $\,\,\xi \in (0,2)$
> 2. $\frac{g'(\xi)}{2}$ for some $\,\,\xi \in (0,2)$
> 3. $\frac{g''(\xi)}{3}$ for some $\,\,\xi \in (0,2)$
> 4. $\frac{g''(\xi)}{6}$ for some $\,\,\xi \in (0,2)$

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: If you don't have to prove the result, you can pick the right answer by considering the function $g(x)=(x-1)^2$. Calculate the error in the approximation, and the second derivative, and compare them.

Comment: Use Taylor series.

Comment: @TonyK By taking $g(x)=(x-1)^2,$ I get $g(1) \approx \frac {1}{12}$. Now what?

Comment: I just noticed that those are first derivatives in your question. Shouldn't they be second derivatives?

Comment: @TonyK thanks a lot.edited the typo.

Comment: This smells like "use Taylor's theorem with remainder", doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error of [midpoint rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method) is $\dfrac{g''(\xi)(b-a)^3}{24}$ (if the interval is not divided into subintervals). In your example $a=0$ and $b=2$.

The answers with the first derivative could be ruled out without knowing the precise error  term. The midpoint rule is exact for linear functions;  the error comes from convexity/concavity which is expressed by the second derivative.